# Proving trigonometric identity $\cos^6A+\sin^6A=1-3 \sin^2 A\cos^2A$

Tags: trigonometry

Show that

> $$\cos^6A+\sin^6A=1-3 \sin^2 A\cos^2A$$

Starting from the left hand side (LHS)

\begin{align}
\text{LHS} &=(\cos^2A)^3+(\sin^2A)^3 \\
&=(\cos^2A+\sin^2A)(\cos^4A-\cos^2A\sin^2A+\sin^4A)\\
&=\cos^4A-\cos^2A\sin^2A+\sin^4A
\end{align}

Can anyone help me to continue from here

Answer (score 3):

Let $a=\cos^2 (A),b=\sin^2 (A) $ . Now use $a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab (a+b) $ also note that $a+b=1$. Hence the proof.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$$  can also be written as

$$a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3-3ab(a+b)$$

Answer (score 2):

[image]
(a+b)^3= a^3 + b^3 + 3ab(a + b)

Answer (score 1):

$$=\cos^4A-\cos^2A\sin^2A+\sin^4A$$
$$=\cos^4A-2\cos^2A\sin^2A+\sin^4A + \cos^2a\sin^2a$$
$$=(\cos^2A-\sin^2A)^2 + \cos^2A\sin^2A=1-3\sin^2A\cos^2A$$
$$(\cos^2A-\sin^2A)^2 + 4\cos^2A\sin^2A=1$$
$2\cos x\sin x=\sin2x$
-> $\sin^22x=4\cos^2\sin^2x$

and

$\cos^2x-\sin^2x =\cos2x$

$$\cos^22A + sin^22A=1$$